# How to get value from particular json format in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a json in this format and I want the value of id and path . I
 have written the following script given below after json format
 .Please help me with a solution.

```
{
"metaData": {
"root": "queue",
"queueStatus": {
  "agentName": "publish-u11cmspu1",
  "agentId": "publish-u11cmspu1",
  "isBlocked": false,
  "isPaused": true,
  "time": 1524644055974,
  "processingSince": 0,
  "lastProcessTime": 1524644046549,
  "nextRetryPeriod": -1524644055975
},
"fields": [
  "id",
  "path",
  "time",
  "userid",
  "type",
  "size",
  "lastProcessed",
  "numProcessed"
 ]
},
"queue": [{
  "id": "anon/7fe264f5-24c6-42df-8409-866783641ca3/2018/4/25/8/14/com.day-u11cmspu1_785",
  "path": "/content/lh/am/en/Homepage2014",
  "time": 1524644051651,
  "userid": "admin",
  "type": "Activate",
  "size": 8781,
  "lastProcessed": 0,
  "numProcessed": 0
}
]
```

Code Below :

```
url ='http://localhost:41102/etc/replication/agents.publish/mobile_notification_agent/jcr:content.queue.json?_dc=1524389867464&agent=mobile_notification_agent'
username='admin'
password='admin'
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = pagehandle.read()
json_response=json.loads(page)
queueid_list = []
for queueid in (json_response['queue']):
    if queueid['type']=='delete':
        queueid_list.append(queueid['id'])
 print queueid_list
```

Comment: don't see no code

Comment: username='admin'
    password='admin'
    passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
    authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    page = pagehandle.read()
    json_response=json.loads(page)
    queueid_list = []
    for queueid in (json_response['queue']):
     if queueid['type']=='delete'
       queueid_list.append(queueid['id'])
     print queueid_list

Comment: Hi Patrick please find the code , I am unable to paste it in the question I have given , giving some error while trying to paste it.

Comment: Hi kdatta, could you make another attempt to post your code? If you can't get the code submission to work here, you could also just put it on https://pastebin.com/ and leave a link here in your question.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback for you error you're getting? (Or describe in greater detail what the problem is if you're not getting an error.)